# Implementing onItemClick and onItemLongClick on an Android GridView

Tags: android-gridview

How do I implement `onItemLongClick` and `onItemClick` for a GridView so that GridView items respond to both events?

Comment: Check out this post. explains just that.
http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/click-long-press-event-listeners-list-activity/

Answer (score 19):

I found that the trick is in the return value of the longclick listener call back. If you return true, `onclick` will not be called after the longclick is called and simple click will invoke only `onclick`. It worked fine for me.